# Deploy Sqlite db file on iOS and Winphone?

Tags: ios, qt, sqlite, windows-phone

Code below it works on Android, but how to do same on iOS and Winphone?

```
QFile dfile("assets:/db/database-last.db3");
if (dfile.exists())
{
    dfile.copy("./database-last.db3");
    QFile::setPermissions("./database-last.db3",QFile::WriteOwner |     QFile::ReadOwner);
 }
```

...

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
 db.setDatabaseName("./database-last.db3");
 db.open();
```

...

in .pro file

```
 deployment.files += database-last.db3
 deployment.path = /assets/db
 INSTALLS += deployment
```

Comment: What errors or warnings did you get?

Comment: You would to say that it will work on ios and winphone without changes?